# MySQL/SQL. Combine two select statement in two columns

Tags: mysql, sql

I need help with a SQL query. I've got two separated SELECT queries:

```
SELECT
     tbl_events.eventName as eventName1
  FROM tbl_events 
  INNER JOIN tbl_users
  ON tbl_events.eventAutorID = tbl_users.userID
  WHERE tbl_users.userID = "6"; 

Output:

eventName1:
eventNametest1
eventNametest2
eventNametest3
eventNametest9
```

and

```
 SELECT
     tbl_events.eventName as eventName2
  FROM tbl_users
  INNER JOIN tbl_participants
  ON tbl_users.userID = tbl_participants.participantUser
  INNER JOIN tbl_events
  ON tbl_participants.participantEvent = tbl_events.eventID
  WHERE tbl_users.userID = "6";  

Output:

eventName2:
eventNametest1
eventNametest3
eventNametest6
eventNametest12
eventNametest15
eventNametest16
```

First query is to select all events (names) created by user with a certain id (eg. id = 6), second is to get all events (event names) where user with certain id is addded as a participant.
How can I combine these statements into one but with results in two different columns? 
The output should look something like this:

```
   eventName1 | eventName2

  eventNametest1   eventNametest1
  eventNametest2   eventNametest3
  eventNametest3   eventNametest6
  eventNametest9   eventNametest12
  NULL             eventNametest15
  NULL             eventNametest16
```

Comment: Do you want the events to line up as in your example?  Edit your question and provide sample data as well as desired results.

Comment: I updated my question.

Answer (score 1):

MySQL doesn't offer `FULL JOIN`.  And, if someone might authorize an event and not participate, you sort of need that.

One method uses `UNION ALL` and variables:

```
SELECT MAX(authName) as authName, MAX(partName) as partName
FROM ((SELECT e.eventName as authName, NULL as partName, (@rne := @rne + 1) as rn
       FROM tbl_events e JOIN
            tbl_users u
            ON e.eventAutorID = u.userID CROSS JOIN
            (SELECT @rna := 0) params
       WHERE u.userID = 6
       ORDER BY eventName
      ) UNION ALL
      (SELECT NULL, e.eventName, (@rnp := @rnp + 1) as rn
       FROM tbl_participants p JOIN
            tbl_events e
            ON e.eventId = p.participantEvent CROSS JOIN
            (SELECT @rnp := 0) params
       WHERE p.participantUser = 6
       ORDER BY e.eventName
      )
     ) ap
GROUP BY rn;
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I don't know why, but your code doesn't work properly. I always get only one row. I updated my question and this is my database:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/oLkGg.jpg

Comment: *I always get only one row in each column. @Gordon Linoff

Comment: @Starkov . . . The lack of initialization of `@rnp` would have affected that column.  But it should have worked fort he authorized events (and it should work for both now).

Answer (score 0):

you just use union reference: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/union.html

Comment: Whilst links to external resources may be valuable, you are expected to explain and include the essence of the answer directly in your post on SO. Please do so.